# Dynamic image upload/browsing path for django-tinymce

Tags: django, django-tinymce, django-filebrowser

I would like to use tinyMCE as the editor for my django application, but have run into some trouble.  I have everything setup, but it appears there is no way to specify the upload path for the image insert/upload function.  I have two specific scenarios where this becomes a problem:

- File browser for user submitted content should not show files uploaded by other users.  I'd like to "jail" them to a specific directory by user id.
- I need a way to link uploaded files with the object they are related to.  That way I can prune those files in the future if the object no longer exists, and I can show only images that are related to that object in the filebrowser.

django-tinymce-filebrowser  automatically sets the upload path to mce_filebrowser/%Y/%m/%d.  There doesn't appear to be an option to change this path in any way.

django-filebrowser has options for setting the upload directory in settings.py, but I haven't been able to find any record of someone overriding that path for a specific modelform instance.  The closest I found was [Django filebrowser, model specific directory parameter for FileBrowserField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911172/django-filebrowser-model-specific-directory-parameter-for-filebrowserfield), but I think the solution there isn't applicable to my situation.

Is anyone using another filebrowser for django-tinymce?  Did you have a similar problem and find a fix for it?  I'd appreciate any points in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a similar approach but instead of modifying the django-filebrowser code I ended up extending the browse() method in a subclass of FileBrowserSite and making the modification there:

```
from django.core.files.storage import DefaultStorage
from filebrowser.sites import FileBrowserSite

class FileBrowserSite(FileBrowserSite):
    def browse(self, request):
        self.directory = self.directory + str(request.user) + '/'
        return super(FileBrowserSite, self).browse(request)

storage = DefaultStorage()
site = FileBrowserSite(name='file', storage=storage)
site.directory = "content/"
```

I put this piece of code on a file called filebrowser.py and the then on my urls.py I did:

```
from .filebrowser import site

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/content/file/', include(site.urls)),  
]
```

I think is a much cleaner approach than modifying the source code, and is working like charm on my project.

Comment: this is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

I've, somewhat hacked this. I'm on grappelli 2.7.2, and django-filebrowser 3.6.1.

I've just added a line to the django-filebrowser file: sites.py:
on the method browse() of the class FileBrowserSite, line ~273, I've added:

```
self._directory_set(DIRECTORY + str(request.user) + "/")
```

It's important though that there is already a directory created for every user, you can make a post_save signal to create a directory every time  a user is created. This solution will not relate the files with the object, but I think that this may be a good start for you and it will isolate files of different users.

For me, this is currently working just fine, I can imagine that this is not the most perfect way to do it, feedback is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I've extended a little bit the answer by [Erasmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6253969/erasmo). Generally, it works great. Thanks! However, as [OriolJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/888245/oriolj) pointed out, every user needs a created directory to use the filebrowser. It is recommended to avoid using signals, so I added the functionality to the custom `FileBrowserSite`.

filebrowser.py

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import DefaultStorage
from filebrowser.sites import FileBrowserSite


class FileBrowserSite(FileBrowserSite):
    def browse(self, request):
        # get directory path from settings to avoid recursion
        self.directory = settings.DIRECTORY + str(request.user) + '/'
        # create a directory for a user if it does not already exist
        full_path = self.storage.location + '/' + self.directory
        if not os.path.exists(full_path):
            os.makedirs(full_path)
        return super().browse(request)


storage = DefaultStorage()


site = FileBrowserSite(name='file', storage=storage)
```

settings.py

```
FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = 'user_content/'
DIRECTORY = ''
```

urls.py

```
from .filebrowser import site

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/content/file/', include(site.urls)),  
]
```

Hope this slight update will save someone a couple of minutes.